# Limit of $\frac{ \sin|z|}{ |z| }$ as $z$ approaches $0$?

Tags: limits

I know that the limit exists for $\frac{\sin(z)}{z }$ as $z$ approaches $0$ using power series expansion. But with modulus operator I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If the limit exists for arbitrary $z\to 0$, then it exists also for the case of positive real $z\to 0$

Comment: This function is called $\operatorname{sinc}x$ for short. Googling that will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

$z\to 0$ if and only if $|z|\to 0$, so
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin|z|}{|z|} = \lim_{|z|\to 0} \frac{\sin|z|}{|z|} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator $|z|$ takes in some complex number $x+iy$ and returns a positive real number $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. As $z\rightarrow 0$, $|z|\rightarrow 0$. Since this is just a limit of a positive real number we can treat it normally. Just substitute to make it more clear $u=|z|$.

$$
\lim_{|z|\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin |z|}{|z|} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin u}{u} = 1
$$